# Advantage of the more general notion of "neighborhoods" in topology

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, terminology

The notion of "open sets" is a fundamental concept in topology. I have been puzzled by (the use of) another slightly more general but closely related one: [neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)). Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$, and a point $p\in X$, a neighbourhood of $p$ is a subset $V$ of $X$ that includes an open set $U$ containing $p$, 
$$
p\in U\subset V.
$$

On the other hand, given a "[neighborhood system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system)" on a set $X$, one can define a topology that is consistent with the notion of "neighborhoods".

This Wikipedia article makes a [remark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Neighbourhood_of_a_point) that "Some mathematicians require that neighbourhoods be open". (For instance, in Munkres's [Topology](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Munkres-Topology-2nd-Edition/9780131816299.html) (c.f. page 96), the statement "$U$ is an open set containing $x$" is considered as equivalent to "$U$ is a neighborhood of $x$".)

**Question**: What is the advantage of the more general notion of "neighborhoods" (that is not required to be open) in practice? Is it simply a matter of taste or does it make significant simplifications in some statement of theorems, proofs or definitions?

---

Notes: Please note that this is question is **not** asking the definitions of "neighborhoods" and "open sets" as the suggested linked question did.

Comment: I've always thought of it as an alternative definition of topologies which appeals to a slightly different intuition, and I think it works particularly well when working with *uniform* spaces, but I am looking forward to more precise answers. Good question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definition of neighborhood and open set in topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157735/definition-of-neighborhood-and-open-set-in-topology)

Comment: @PhysMath: thank you for the link. But no, I am not asking about the definitions of these two notions.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2766246/4280), e.g.

Answer (score 19):

It makes for easier formulation of some theorems or definitions: a space can be called locally compact if it has a (base of) compact neighbourhoods, or locally connected if it has a local base of connected neighbourhoods (regardless of openness).

The formulation of local continuity is also easy: $f$ is continuous at $x$ if $f^{-1}[N]$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ for every neighbourhood $N$ of $f(x)$.

$X$ is regular iff every point has a local base of closed neighbourhoods.

A filter $\mathcal{F}$ converges to $x$ iff it contains all neighbourhoods of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the formulation of local continuity, the definition is the same if one requires neighborhoods to be open, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think the formulation of local continuity would work with open neighborhoods: consider $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f = \chi_{[0, \infty)}$.  Then $f$ is continuous at 1; $(1/2, 3/2)$ is an open neighborhood of $f(1)$; but $f^{-1}[(1/2, 3/2)] = [0, \infty)$ is not an open neighborhood of 1.

Comment: @DanielSchepler quite right, we'd have to resort to "contains a neighbourhood" in that case.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one example when it is convenient not to require neighborhoods to be open. The following is either a lemma or a definition:

A map $f: X\to Y$ of two topological spaces is continuous at a point  $x\in X$ if and only if for every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Note similarity with the definition of a continuous map.

This lemma/definition will be false if we were to require open neighborhoods. The alternative (when requiring open neighborhoods is heavier) is heavier:

A map $f: X\to Y$ of two topological spaces is continuous at a point  $x\in X$ if and only if for every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(V)$ contains a neighborhood of $x$.

A historic remark. Bourbaki’s “General Topology” does not require neighborhoods to be open. The convention that neighborhoods are open is common in the US literature and, I think, can be traced to Kelley’s “General Topology.”

Comment: Why is that necessary? It looks like it would still be correct in the latter formulation with just requiring it to be a neighborhood. I must be missing something here, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I see it now.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Isn't first one also "iff"? can you provide an example that fail to be continuous by "$f^{-1} $ of open sets is open"?

Comment: @C.F.G: That direction is OK, it is the opposite one that fails: A map can be discontinuous but continuous at a point. Hence, preimages of open neighborhoods of a point can fail to be open, while the map is continuous at the point.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Sorry if I am commenting on an old post. Hatcher defined covering maps using open sets but Fulton using open neighborhoods. Are they equivalent?

Comment: @C.F.G I never read Fulton's book. I suggest, you ask a separate question.