# Alternative definitions of neighbourhood of a point

Tags: general-topology

There are some text like Munkres and Rudin that defines neighbourhood of a point x to be an open set that contains x, while other text defines neighbourhood to be any set that contains an open set that contains x. I was wondering which definition is the one that math journals actually use?

Answer (score 2):

Both are used, and most authors specify which version they use. I prefer the general one, as it makes for some shorter expressions of concepts. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3635003/4280) I also give some examples in my answer.